# Will installing Unity 8 on 15.04 affect my current Unity desktop?

Tags: unity, desktop-environments, 15.04

I would like to play around with Unity 8 on my laptop. I am currently running 15.04 with Unity and I'm afraid installing Unity 8 will break something in my current desktop? Will just get another desktop option when I log in so I easily can return to my current desktop?

Answer (score 0):

Normally it shouldn't affect your current desktop. But since it is unstable, if you are not an expert and if your computer is the one you use on a daily basis, I would highly recommend you not to install it.

If you still install it, you can switch between your desktops on the login screen, clicking on the «Ubuntu» icon that is in the login field, next to your name.

Comment: I've installed unity8 in 15.04 and there's not the icon to switch session type next to the username. It used to be there when I tried unity8 in 14.10 but now not anymore... any other experience?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it won't affect your Unity 7, just that the unity 8 can't be used that much as a daily driver.

Finished installing mine, and just staring at the login screen now, nothing working.